# Spring having trouble mapping 2 similar RequestMapping routes

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing a web app, in which it allows users to retrieve unique items in different types of warehouses. 
I have 2 GET API endpoints that I'm trying to define in my controller class.

```
Retrieve items related to a particular warehouse.
api-item/v1/items?warehouse="001"
Parameter: warehouse

Retrieve all items from all warehouses
api-item/v1/items
```

ItemController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ReturnResponse getItems() {

        List <Product> itemsList = itemService.getItems();

        return myDefinedUtilities.getHttpStatusResponse("success.items", HttpStatus.OK, itemsList, null);
    }




@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ReturnResponse getItemsForWarehouse(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "warehouse") String wareHouseId) {

        List <Product> itemsList = itemService.getItemsForWarehouse(wareHouseId);

        return myDefinedUtilities.getHttpStatusResponse("success.items", HttpStatus.OK, itemsList, null);
    }
```

I've defined test methods that tests these 2 methods in my JUnit test class, mocking the service class: itemService. I was not able to run any test methods, with the following error displayed:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at ....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'itemController' method 
public com.trinet.domain.common.ReturnResponse com.trinet.web.controller.product.itemController.getItemsForWarehouse(java.lang.String)
to {[/v1/items],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'itemController' bean method
public com.trinet.domain.common.ReturnResponse com.trinet.web.controller.product.itemController.getItems() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request Mapping Annotation takes another which is `params` which can be used to differentiate between two routes. As Roman Suggested, it will be like below.

`@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET, params="warehouse")`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ReturnResponse getItems() {

    List <Product> itemsList = itemService.getItems();

    return myDefinedUtilities.getHttpStatusResponse("success.items", HttpStatus.OK, itemsList, null);
}




@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET, params="warehouse")
public ReturnResponse getItemsForWarehouse(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "warehouse") String wareHouseId) {

    List <Product> itemsList = itemService.getItemsForWarehouse(wareHouseId);

    return myDefinedUtilities.getHttpStatusResponse("success.items", HttpStatus.OK, itemsList, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `params` of the `RequestMapping` annotation. It allows to define parameters to differentiate similar mappings.

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/items", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "warehouse")
    public ReturnResponse getItemsForWarehouse(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "warehouse") String wareHouseId) {

    List <Product> itemsList = itemService.getItemsForWarehouse(wareHouseId);

    return myDefinedUtilities.getHttpStatusResponse("success.items", HttpStatus.OK, itemsList, null);
}
```